# After the upadate of the ide intellJ the new class is not opening

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH2ES.png)

when i make a new class after making the new package in the ide  IntelliJ the above error is shown.
Please help me to fix this error what should I do now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use spaces in a class name. Try naming it something like 'MyClass'.

And please read official documentation about [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Ohh this was literally a silly mistake.By the way thank you

Comment: No problem at all. Marking the reply as accepted is a common way of saying 'thank you' on SO ;)